# How to test a controller function using phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm learning tests with PHP, i need to test a function that returns a view and i still can't find a way to do this. For example the function bellow:

```
public function getEmails(){
    if (Defender::hasPermission("users")) {
        $index = $this->diretorioPrincipal;
        $route = $this->nameView;

        return view("{$this->index}.{$this->nameView}.emails", compact('index', 'route'));
    } else {
        return redirect("/{$this->index}");
    }
}
```

Can somebody plase explain how to test this function?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a test with `php artisan make:test <TestName>`. Afterwards in your test you will typically call the setup method for initializing general values. (maybe a user or a model)
I dont know the route to your method so lets assume it is `route('myMethod')`, You will also have to use 2 diffrent users: `$user1` and `$user2` one should have the permission `users` and one should not have it so that both cases are tested.

```
class SomeControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** 
    * Setup stuff
    **/
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }
   //All tests must be written as test<SomeName>
   public function testMyFunction()
    {
       //user1 does have the permission
       $response = $this->actingAs($user1)->get(route('myFunction'));
       //the view response has code status 200 so we will check if the response is ok = 200
       $resp->assertOk();
       
       //user2 does not have the permission
       $response = $this->actingAs($user2)->get(route('myFunction'));
       //the redirect response is has status code 302 so we will check if the response is a redirect = 302
       $resp->assertRedirect();
    }
}
```

This is some basic approach, but I tried to incorporate your method. If anything is unclear just keep on asking.